# LayoutConstraint Conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Say, in the xib file I add a UIView and its width and height is fixed. No LayoutConstraint added in the xib file.I connect the UIView with an IBOutlet property "contentView", then in the viewDidLoad method I do :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:-20.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
}
```

When I ran the program , it seems that constraint conflict happened, but I don not know how to solve this problem:

```
2014-10-14 09:37:57.436 TestAutoLayout[651:53850] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try   this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code   that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the        UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7a028de0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7a029380](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a029470 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7a028ed0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIView:0x7a029380(320)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a028620 UIView:0x7a029380.right == UIView:0x7a029470.right - 20>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a02f600 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7a029470(320)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a028620 UIView:0x7a029380.right == UIView:0x7a029470.right - 20>
```

For some reason I have to set the constraint in program. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have fixed the width at 320 but now you are trying to set the right boundary to view width-20 (so 300), which results in a conflict.

Comment: It`s not right. However , in the xib file , if I set the frame as {-20, 0, 320 , 568} , conflict will not happen. @Paulw11

Comment: maybe I misread it, but you have the same issue.  The width is 320 and the constraints require it to be 340 (-20 + 320)

Comment: You may want to call `[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints]` before adding your constraints - either set all constraints programatically or all via IB.  You can also tick the box in IB that removes a constraint at runtime if you want it for layout purposes but plan to replace the constraint programatically

Comment: Yes! IB seems adds explicit constraints which conflict with the constraints I add. @Paulw11